# Altium hides the whole board and other connections when I'm routing

Tags: altium

I was working with Altium when suddenly it began to behave in this way

[image]

I do not know but I guess that some shortcuts were pressed to pass in this visualization mode.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try SHIFT+S to browse layer modes. If that does not work try SHIFT+C.

Comment: @Rev1.0 It doesn't work.

Comment: Try Ctrl and + keys and Ctrl and - Keys also

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution to my problem: the `Increase Mask Level` in the View menu. The shortcut for this function are the `'` and the `ì` keys in my program. Maybe I pressed the `'` key too much time without realizing it.